# WM_MOUSEWHEEL not working for horizontal scrolling?

Tags: winapi

I just spent a few hours trying to figure out why Spy++ would show `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` events for horizontal scrolling, but I couldn't see them showing up in my code. Why am I not seeing these events?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns our - as you get older - you start missing minor details as you read. In this case, I missed that `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` that I was trying to handle in my code is not the same as `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL` I was seeing in Spy++. `WM_MOUSEHWHEEL` is the horizontal version of `WM_MOUSEWHEEL`. This must be a common mistake!